# Jmeter Regular expression match number

Tags: regex, jmeter, correlation

I have two values to **correlate** and I am able to capture them in two parameters successfully. I am taking random values using `-1` in match number, but I actually wanted in a way like, let's  say my first value **randomly** take the match number as `7` and I want my second value also should take the same match num as 7.

Please help me how I can simulate this .

Comment: Can you show us, what ave tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, (as you've discovered), JMeter determines the 'random' independently. What you'll need to do is capture each potential value (with a `-1`) for both of var1 and var2. Then after your Regexes, add a `Beanshell Postprocessor` that gets a random number n, then picks the nth var1 and var2:

```
String random_number = Integer(random.nextInt(vars.get("var1_name_matchNr"))).toString;
vars.put("var1_name_chosen",vars.get("var1_name_" + random_number));
vars.put("var2_name_chosen",vars.get("var2_name_" + random_number));
```

Comment: what is "var1_name_matchNr" in the above mentioned example?

Comment: whenever you use a `Regular Expression Extractor` with the `-1` option, it will generate a variable that tells you how many it extracted. So if it extracted 3 things that match `var1_name`, then `var1_name_matchNr`=3.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to extract random regex value, and put it into 2 variables. If so, I would suggest doing something like...

After you get random regex value, add beanshell in which you will paste value you got with regex into the second variable.

So if your variable in regex is "foo1", just add beanshell sampler with:

```
vars.put("foo2", vars.get("foo1"));
```

EDIT:

This would be better as Java sampler, but I think it should work in BeanShell sampler as well.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;


String previousResponse = JMeterContextService.getContext()
        .getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString();

String locationLinkRegex = "\"locationId\": (.+?),";

String myLocationId = RegexMethod(previousResponse, locationLinkRegex,
        true);
String myLocationLink = RegexMethod(
        previousResponse,
        "\"locationId\": ".concat(myLocationId).concat(
                ", \"locationLink\":(.+?))\""), false);

JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables()
        .put("locationId", myLocationId);
JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables()
        .put("locationLink", myLocationLink);   

private static String RegexMethod(String response, String regex,
        Boolean random) {
    Random ran = new Random();
    String result = "No matcher!";
    ArrayList<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
    allMatches = null;
    if (random) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.UNICODE_CASE).matcher(
                response);
        while (m.find()) {
            allMatches.add(m.group());
        }
        result = allMatches.get(ran.nextInt(allMatches.size()));
    } else {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.UNICODE_CASE).matcher(
                response);
        m.find();
        result = m.group(1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Exception handling needs to be implemented as well...

EDIT2:

And the Regex-method as recursive (returns both values as CSV, and can be use only if locationId is unique):

```
private static String RegexMethod(String response, String regex) {
    Random ran = new Random();
    String result = "No matcher!";
    List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Find LocationId:
    Matcher m1 = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.UNICODE_CASE).matcher(
            response);
    while (m1.find()) {
        allMatches.add(m1.group());
    }
    result = allMatches.get(ran.nextInt(allMatches.size())).concat(",");

    // Find LocationLink and return the CSV string:

    return result += RegexMethod(response, "\"locationId\": "
            .concat(result.substring(result.length()-1)).concat(", \"locationLink\":(.+?))\""));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but thats not the actual case. Let me take an example. Lets say my first value is location-name and second value is location id. I have selected match num for location-name as random (i.e. 0) and if my locationname picked the value with match num 3, I want the same match num for the location id. hope this is clear now.

Comment: Can you please put some response (source) example, so I can exactly see and help you... I get what you want, but to be able to help you I need to see an example... :-)

Comment: "locationId": 1234,
      "locationLink": "Here URL of the locationlink"                                                           Its a Json response, where I am trying to capture all locations with location link and location id

Comment: Thanks for that, will check and let you know.

Comment: Btw, RegexMethod can be done as a recursive, so if you prefer that I can edit the answer...

Comment: After some thoughts, it would not be wise doing recursion here. It can be done, but has no real point and would be useless resulting with dirty code. Did you manage to implement this?

Comment: For your question... It can be done by changing the Method calling, and return. And instead of calling it twice, you would make a call for the second regex inside... And for the return you could get one Pair (Id and Link).

Comment: I am not clear on how it can be done.. Could you please explain. And its not a regular expression its a json post processor

Comment: I have put EDIT2 in the answer. That's recursion but it has some limitations in terms of loacationId rarity. It needs to be unique. And what exactly do you think when you say Json PostProc?

Comment: I have checked the response of the location link  and I observed that the location id is taking from that as well, as I have correlated from this sampler which is taking the corresponding location id though the location link picked randomly from the previous request, which resolved my query. Thanks for the response. Hope to talk to you again.